# Cert manager issuing certs for Strimzi kafka deployment

Tags: cert-manager, strimzi

I am working on strimzi kafka.I want to deploy kafka with self signed certs issued by certmanager instead of strimzi operator/kafka provided selfsigned certs.
I have gone through the strizmi documentation but I didn't find solution to integrate cert manger with strimzi kafka/operator.
When we deploy kafka we can see many secrets(with certs) are being created in the namespace.If I want all those secrets/certs issued by certs manager to work with kafka how I can do it.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cert Manager to provide a listener certificate s described in this [blog post](https://strimzi.io/blog/2021/05/07/deploying-kafka-with-lets-encrypt-certificates/). But there is currently no easy way to use it for the internal CAs. You can follow this [proposal](https://github.com/strimzi/proposals/pull/46) which might make it possible in the future.